# How Do I Set AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed In IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

How do I set AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed in IIS Express on Windows 7? I know where the IIS Express config files are but I don't see the AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed setting there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it also could not be found in IIS (usual version and not express) Schema, so it's ok as IIS Express mimics usual IIS features.

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\schema
```

In order to set `AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed` in IIS Express, you could use the `appcmd` for IIS Express which could be found in:

```
%ProgramFiles%\IIS Express\\IIS Express\appcmd.exe
```

The command to set it is similar with the one we set in usual IIS through appcmd:

```
appcmd set config -section:asp -limits.maxRequestEntityAllowed:int
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Comment: C:\Program Files\IIS Express>appcmd set config /section:asp /maxRequestEntity
Allowed:1073741824
ERROR ( message:Unknown attribute "maxRequestEntityAllowed".  Replace with -?
 for help. )

Comment: Also tried with ASPMaxRequestEntity and got the same C:\Program Files\IIS Express>appcmd set config /section:asp /ASPMaxRequestEntity
Allowed:1073741824
ERROR ( message:Unknown attribute "ASPMaxRequestEntityAllowed".  Replace with -?
 for help. )

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please kindly test the updated answer above and let me know the result. Thanks

Comment: C:\Program Files\IIS Express>appcmd set config -section:asp -limits.maxRequestEn
tityAllowed:1073741824
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/asp" for "MACHINE/WEB
ROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"